# How to include PHP variables in wp_mail()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `wp_mail()` to send out an email with all the information from a post, including all its custom fields.

I've saved the post, when I click the email button this then sends an AJAX  request to my function which includes `get_post_meta()` and `wp_mail()`. This should get all the saved post meta and send it out via an email.

But no joy – this just sends an empty email. Am I missing something?

```
function implement_ajax_operatoremail() {  

/*
*Construct the email
*/

    //The recipients    
    $title = get_the_title( $ID );
    $to = 'myemailaddress';
    $subject = 'Booking Confirmation : ' . $title; 
    $headers = 'From: clientname';

    //the message
    $message = 'here is the ' . $title . 'but it aint working' ;

    //send the email
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

}

add_action('wp_ajax_operatoremail', 'implement_ajax_operatoremail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_operatoremail', 'implement_ajax_operatoremail');
```

Comment: From where the $ID coming ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$title = get_the_title( $ID );
$to = 'myemailaddress';
$subject = 'Booking Confirmation : ' . $title; 
$message  = "Dear ".$user->first_name.",\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "Your Booking is confirmed \r\n\r\n";
$message .= "Thanks!"."\r\n";
$headers = "From: Company Name <info@example.com>"."\r\n";                      
$mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Please replace code with this one.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped with me with some syntax formatting, however this wasnt the problem in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that could be missing here is $attachments? It seems like you use variable inside your function but do not assign anything it?

Also try assigning something like $title = 'test title'; as one of comments stated your $ID is coming from nowhere?

Another thing is headers, please correct your $headears to match :
"From: "Example User" "

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't really answer my question,. The error was that I was trying to get variables from the post ID, the post ID hadn't been sent so hardly surprising. Once i sent the post id to my function, all was good.

Thanks all.